# How much produce becomes bikkurim (first fruits)?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, bikkurim-first-fruits

How much produce becomes bikkurim (first fruits)?

Rambam says: [Hilchos Bikkurim Chap 2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002528/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-2.htm)

> Halacha 19 How should one separate the first fruits? A person descends
>   to his field, sees a fig tree, a cluster [of grapes], and/or a
>   pomegranate tree that has budded, and ties them with a reed.50 He
>   should say: "These are the first fruits.' They become designated as
>   first fruits even though they are attached to the ground after they
>   have been given that title, even though they have not ripened
>   entirely.51
>
> When they ripen and are reaped from the ground, it is not necessary to
>   designate them again. If he did not designate them while attached or
>   call them first fruits and then he reaped them, he should designate
>   them after he reaps them.52

This implies to me that only some of the fruits are bikkurim.

Rambam continues:

> If his entire harvest becomes impure, he should not designate the
>   impure produce as first fruits. Instead, as an initial preference, he
>   should set aside other produce as first fruits for the impure produce.
>   It appears to me that if he does not have other produce, to separate
>   [as first fruits], he should not set them aside to be destroyed.53
>   Similarly, it appears to me54 that if the first fruits become impure,
>   he should not use them as kindling for a furnace, because they are
>   like objects consecrated for the Temple.55
>
> Halacha 20 When a person set aside his first fruits and they rotted
>   away,56 were taken by others, lost, stolen, or became impure,57 he is
>   obligated to set aside others in place ofthem,58 as [Exodus 23:119]
>   states: '...bring to the house of God your Lord.' This teaches that
>   one is liable to replace them until he brings them to the Temple
>   Mount.59

and now by mentioning the entire harvest I am not sure.

Comment: ...הפאה והביכורים והראיון...

Comment: Where does the translator get the word "tree" from? That is not how I would have read the _Rambam_: "כיצד מפרישין הבכורים יורד אדם לתוך שדהו ורואה תאנה שבכרה אשכול ענבים שבכרו רמון שבכר קושרן בגמי ואומר הרי אלו בכורים"

Comment: @msh210 תאנה can mean "fig tree" or "fig" (eg. [Yirmiyahu 8:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1108.htm#13))

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm well aware of that. But in this context, "tree" doesn't seem to make much sense. He ties a band around the tree? I mean, it's possible, but it just doesn't seem likely (nor is it a good analogue to אשכול ענבים, which a single fig is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> הבכורים אין להם שיעור מן התורה אבל מדבריהם צריך להפריש אחד מששים והרוצה לעשות כל שדהו בכורים עושהו:‏
>   The Bikkurim have no measurement from the Torah, but [the rabbis] required separating one sixtieth; and if one wants to make his entire field Bikkurim, he may.

[Rambam Bikkurim 2:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=39&perek=2&halocha=17&hilite=)